# Constraint issue with pyomo involving a scalar

Tags: constraints, pyomo, scalar

working on an economic optimization problem with pyomo, I would like to add a constraint to prevent the product of the commodity quantity and its price to go below zero (<0), avoiding a negative revenue. It appears that all the data are in a dataframe and I can't setup a constraint like:

```
def positive_revenue(model, t)
    return model.P * model.C >=0
model.positive_rev = Constraint(model.T, rule=positive_revenue)
```

The system returns the error that the price is a scalar and it cannot process it. Indeed the price is set as such in the model:

```
model.T = Set(doc='quarter of year', initialize=df.quarter.tolist(), ordered=True)



model.P = Param(initialize=df.price.tolist(), doc='Price for each quarter')

##while the commodity is:
model.C = Var(model.T, domain=NonNegativeReals)
```

I just would like to apply that for each timestep (quarter of hour here) that:

price(t) * model.C(t) >=0

Can someone help me to spot the issue ? Thanks

Here are more information:

df dataframe:

```
df                   time_stamp  price Status  imbalance  
quarter                                                                                                                                  
0       2021-01-01 00:00:00  64.84  Final         16          
1       2021-01-01 00:15:00  13.96  Final         38          
2       2021-01-01 00:30:00  12.40  Final         46
```

index = quarter from 0 till 35049, so it is ok

```
Here is the df.info()
#   Column          Non-Null Count  Dtype         
---  ------          --------------  -----         
 0   time_stamp      35040 non-null  datetime64[ns]
 1   price           35040 non-null  float64       
 2   Status          35040 non-null  object        
 3   imbalance       35040 non-null  int64
```

I modified the to_list() > to_dict() in model.T but still facing the same issue:

KeyError: "Cannot treat the scalar component 'P' as an indexed component" at the time model.T is defined in the model parameter, set and variables.

Here is the constraint where the system issues the error:

```
def revenue_positive(model,t):
        for t in model.T:
            return (model.C[t] * model.P[t]) >= 0
    
    model.positive_revenue = Constraint(model.T,rule=revenue_positive)
```

Can't figure it out...any idea ?
**UPDATE**
Model works after dropping an unfortunate 'quarter' column somewhere...after I renamed the index as quarter.
It runs but i still get negative revenues, so the constraints seems not working at present, here is how it is written:

def revenue_positive(model,t):
for t in model.T:
return (model.C[t] * model.P[t]) >= 0

```
model.positive_revenue = Constraint(model.T,rule=revenue_positive)
```

What am I missing here ? Thanks for help, just beginning

Comment: see my edits below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site.

The problem you appear to be having is that you are not building your model parameter `model.P` as an indexed component.  I believe you likely want it to be indexed by your set `model.T`.

When you make indexed params in `pyomo` you need to initialize it with some key:value pairing, like a python dictionary.  You can make that from your data frame by re-indexing your data frame so that the quarter labels are the index values.

**Caution:  The construction you have for model.T and this *assume* there are no duplicates in the quarter names**.

If you have duplicates (or get a warning) then you'll need to do something else.  If the quarter labels are unique you can do this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pyomo.environ as pyo
df = pd.DataFrame({'qtr':['Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7'], 'price':[12.80, 11.50, 8.12]})
df.set_index('qtr', inplace=True)
print(df)

m = pyo.ConcreteModel()
m.T = pyo.Set(initialize=df.index.to_list())
m.price = pyo.Param(m.T, initialize=df['price'].to_dict())

m.pprint()
```

#### which should get you:

```
     price
qtr       
Q5   12.80
Q6   11.50
Q7    8.12

1 Set Declarations
    T : Size=1, Index=None, Ordered=Insertion
        Key  : Dimen : Domain : Size : Members
        None :     1 :    Any :    3 : {'Q5', 'Q6', 'Q7'}

1 Param Declarations
    price : Size=3, Index=T, Domain=Any, Default=None, Mutable=False
        Key : Value
         Q5 :  12.8
         Q6 :  11.5
         Q7 :  8.12

2 Declarations: T price
```

edit for clarity...

##### NOTE:

The first argument when you create a `pyomo` parameter is the indexing set.  If this is not provided, `pyomo` assumes that it is a scalar.   You are missing the **set** as shown in my example and highlighted with arrow here:  :)

```
                     |
                     |
                     |
                     V
m.price = pyo.Param(m.T, initialize=df['price'].to_dict())
```

Also note, you will need to initialize `model.P` with a **dictionary** as I have in the example, **not** a list.

Comment: Well not there yet unfortunately, I still ge ther error: 

ERROR: Constructing component 'P' from data=None failed: KeyError: "Cannot
    treat the scalar component 'P' as an indexed component"

Comment: Somehow the “thing” you are using as the initialization is `None`.  Print it off and investigate.  If you are stuck, go up and edit your post by adding the new code you are using and a couple lines from your data frame `df.head()` and comment back.

Comment: thks will give a look this evening. cheers

Comment: Ok I saw that for a reason when I created the 'quarter' index, this created a column. I dropped it and now the model runs. I am still struggling with the constraints that is not applied on the model.... any thoughts ? see comments above

Comment: Questions are supposed to focus on 1 issue, rather than a continuous debugging effort.  If this answered your orig. question, you could close it out by accepting the answer with the check mark.  If you have issues with another constraint, consider opening a new question after doing your own troubleshooting, and include a reproducible example.  For T/S, I’d recommend using only a sliver of your data and `pprint`ing the model

Comment: Got the point will do. Thanks